# How to resolve transforming http response in intercetp method from nestjs interceptor

Tags: typescript, nestjs, interceptor

I'm trying to transform a http response inside a interceptor from nestjs,I've read the interceptor from [nestjs docs](https://docs.nestjs.com/interceptors#aspect-interception) but the tap method seems to not doing it and it's the map that does that but tried with map and didn't get the expected result, I share the intercep() method for advice or hints:

```
export interface Response<T> { data: T: }

@Injectable()
export class LogsInterceptor<T> implements NestInterceptor<T, Response<T>> {
  constructor(
    private logService: LogsService,
    private jwtService: JwtService,
  ) {}

  intercept(
    context: ExecutionContext,
    next: CallHandler<any>,
  ): Observable<Response<T>> {
    //const request = context.switchToHttp().getRequest();
    let responseStatus = context.switchToHttp().getResponse();
    let log: ILogModel;
    let id: number;
    let args: any = context.getArgs()[0];

    return next.handle().pipe(
      tap({
        next: async (data) => {
          id = this.setId(args, id, data);
          log = {
            ip: args.hostname,
            id,
            tipo: args.method,
            path: args.originalUrl,
            query: args.query,
            params: args.params,
            body: args.body,
            token: args.headers.authorization,
            response: data,
            statuscode: responseStatus.statusCode,
          };
          let idT: number = 0;
          idT = await this.logRequest(log);
          let respuestaF = {
            id: idT,
            data,
          };
          return respuestaF;
        },
        error: (error) => {
          id = this.setId(args, id, error);
          log = {
            ip: args.hostname,
            id,
            tipo: args.method,
            path: args.originalUrl,
            query: args.query,
            params: args.params,
            body: args.body,
            token: args.headers.authorization,
            response: error,
            statuscode: error.status,
          }:
          this.logRequest(log);
          return error;
        },
      }),
    );
  }
```

Comment: What are you getting when you use `map` from `rxjs`?

Comment: could you facilitate an example of how to use the happy path and catch error model inside a map?

Comment: `map`'s don't have a way to catch errors, you'd need to use a `catchError` operator